# gcc strange compilation in C correct only when warnings

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, warnings

i got a very strange compilation issue.

I want to make hexadecimal/decimal conversion librairies (without stdio).

Here is the output when there is no warnings but the result is false (should be 2014) :

```
xx@xxx:~/fcgi/test# sudo gcc dec.c -lm -o dec
xx@xxx:~/fcgi/test# ./dec 7DE
0
```

And the output when there is warnings but the result is correct !

```
xx@xxx:~/fcgi/test# sudo gcc dec.c -lm -o dec
In file included from libhex.h:24:0,
                 from dec.c:2:
libhex.c: In function ‘ishexchar’:
libhex.c:54:12: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
libhex.c:54:23: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
libhex.c:54:33: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
libhex.c:54:45: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
libhex.c:54:55: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
libhex.c:54:66: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
xx@xxx:~/fcgi/test# ./dec 7DE
2014
```

Here is the function's code, which is checking for correct hexadecimal character's codes with a a very little mistake (no * before c) but working function :

```
int ishexchar (const int *c) {
    return (c < 48 || (c > 57 && c < 65) || (c > 70 && c < 97) || c > 102) ? 1 : 0;
};
```

It's called like this (where c is a character casted with int)

```
ishexchar(&c);
```

Thanks for your read. If you've the same compilation issue tell me. And also tell me if that kind of librairy interrest you, because i will publish the code on github as soon as the problem is solve. For my purpose it's for use in FastCGI which have not totally implementation of stdio.

**EDIT:** Here the github for the librairy i made for hexadecimal/decimal conversions : https://github.com/kevmuret/libhex

Comment: I'd name this function `ishexdigit()`, at least after it worked as intended ... ;-)

Comment: Why are you invoking gcc with `sudo`?  There's no reason to be root to compile something, unless your $CWD is /etc or /bin or some silliness. Much like the advice of not invoking the gods for trivial things... don't invoke root unless you __really__ need to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing `*` is a *big* mistake. Your function, as it stands, is comparing a pointer value (which is a memory address) to an integer. That explains the warning, which is telling you *literally* what you're doing, and why this could be wrong.

Either change the functions' signature or dereference the pointer when comparing to the int (to compare the actual int value):

```
return (*c < 48 || (*c > 57 && *c < 65) || (*c > 70 && *c < 97) || *c > 102) ? 1 : 0;
```

Or write:

```
int ishexchar (int c)
{}
//and call like:
ishexchar(c);
```

PS:

You don't need to cast a char to an int, you can compare a `char` to an `int`:

```
char x = 'a';
if (x == 97)
   puts("This is perfectly valid");
```

Not sure about your function, though: `c < 48` means that you consider chars like `"` and `!` to be valid hex chars. I wouldn't. The valid chars, IMO are 0-9, a-f and A-F. No more, no less:

```
int ishexchar(int c)
{
    return ((c > 47 && c < 58) || (c > 96 && c < 103) || (c > 64 && c < 71) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

That should do the trick, cf [codepad](http://codepad.org/svXboyxB).

Keep this in mind: [The ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: I used the first solution, the compilation have no warnings, but the result is incorrect. That's what i don't understand how it's possible can you do the test and tell me if you've the same problem.

Comment: @kevmuret: Just added a bit to my answer: you perform checks on the char that imply that certain NON ASCII chars are valid, but you don't seem to accept numerics

Comment: Thanks for your remark about the `c < 48` the problem was just the `? 1 : 0` the correct code is `? 0 : 1` at the end, it was just an inversion of sens. It's show the importance of right strict code in C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are clearly doing what the warning says, i.e. comparing a pointer an integer.

If `c` is `const int *`, then `c < 48` compares a pointer and an integer.

There is no point in passing a pointer to a function like this; remove the `*` and make it just

```
bool ishexchar(int c);
```

If you really want to pass a pointer, you need to de-reference that pointer inside the function, i.e. use `*c` to get the value that `c` points at. I fail to see the point about "duplicating memory" though, you really should not need to pass a pointer since the character is not larger than the pointer there is no win.

Further, you should never have "magic constants" in your code when you can avoid it. Unless you're *trying* to target only ASCII, the comparisons should be against `'0'` and `'9'` for the decimal digits. You cannot rely on the characters A-F and a-f to have any particular ordering or encoding, so if you don't want to be ASCII-only you must do those tests differently.

Finally, the numerical result of all those booleans will be 0 or 1, there's no point in using `?:` to force it.

Comment: OK but i don't want the memory to be duplicated (copied).
It should be working great with * but it's not !

Comment: @kevmuret: If you really don't want memory duplication, a macro or `inline` function would be the best fit. However: rest assured that compilers can optimize a lot more than you think

Comment: Yes you're surely right that compiler can optimize more than i think, but if i can write it correctly i do it. I'm a begginner in this language what is a macro ?